# CGImageCreateCopy vs. CGImageRetain

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-graphics

A `CGImageRef` doesn't appear to have any mutating operations. Copying a `CGImageRef` does not copy the `CGDataProviderRef` (determined through experimentation). So if `CGImageRef` is an immutable type, is there any reason to `copy` vs. `retain`?

Comment: Its there for completeness, just like copy on a NSString or NSArray. It makes subclassing potentially easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A CGImageRef doesn't appear to have any mutating operations

There are no public functions to modify `CGImage`, however, that doesn't mean `CGImageRef` is immutable. `CGImageRef` is opaque, that is, the internal structure is not documented but there are still ways to modify it.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = ...
struct CGImage image = *imageRef;
//if you know the internal structure, you can do things like
image.provider = ...
```

I guess Core Graphics often make internal copies of the image, for example, `CGImageCreateCopyWithColorSpace` probably uses `CGImageCreateCopy` internally. Copies can also be made when the image is being drawn.

And of course, this is a very good design for "subclassing" (not really subclassing since we have structs, not objects).

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. Although I don't think another class _should_ circumvent the public interface, I'm sure it's been done.

Answer (score 0):

No. Sometimes you need to `copy`, for instance you can get the `CGImageRef` backing a `UIImage` but it would be bad practice to try and `retain` it - you would in that case make a `copy`.

Comment: Why would it be "bad practice"? A CGImageRef is just another immutable object, so there's no need to ever make a copy, and retain will undoubtedly work for it.

Comment: While the public face of this object is immutable, who knows what liberties UIImage or Foundation internals might do. Obviously YMMV - for me, I'd keep the UIImage around if I needed to access the CGImageRef occasionally, or copy it. Technically, from what we know, you should be able to retain it - I just would not personally.